# Apache directory listing as json

Tags: apache, directory-listing, mod-autoindex

Is it possible to have the directory listing in apache return json instead of html?

I'm completely unexperienced with Apache, but I've browsed the documentation for IndexOptions and mod_autoindex. It seems like there's no built in way to configure the output.

Comment: Have you looked at [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html)?

Comment: Good catch - that's exactly what I needed to use.

Comment: I wrote and Apache module that does just that [https://github.com/teknopaul/mod_upload](https://github.com/teknopaul/mod_upload) Project has two modules mod_jsonindex.so is the one you want FYI nginx has json indexing built in.

Comment: slightly unrelated, but `caddy` does it ootb if the request comes with the header `Accept: application/json`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I looked at the code in apache source in `modules/generators/mod_autoindex.c` and the HTML generation is static. You *could* rewrite this to output JSON, simply search for all the `ap_rputs` and `ap_rvputs` function calls and replace the HTML with the appropriate JSON. That's seems like a lot of work though.

I think I would do this instead...

In the Apache configuration for this site, change to...

```
DirectoryIndex ls_json.php index.php index.html
```

And then place `ls_json.php` script into the any directory for which you want a JSON encoded listing:

```
// grab the files
$files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));

// remove "." and ".." (and anything else you might not want)
$output = [];
foreach ($files as $file)
  if (!in_array($file, [".", ".."]))
    $output[] = $file;

// out we go
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I ended up using. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) as follows - create a php script and list your directories how you want (set content-type as appropriate).